# What STL container should i use to walk a tree?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I dont know whether bidirectional means i can write rbegin() or if i can decrease an iterator.

I have a tree that is forward only which isnt a problem. I'd like to walk it which is. What i am doing at the moment is every time i visit a branch i push current_iterator. Now the problem is i am iterating through a branch and called a function. The function needs to visit the previous nodes in the list.

So i wrote `it=current_iterator` and plan to write `--it` to rewind. As a quick test i wrote `--o.begin()==o.end()` to see if i can do this. I got a assert error.

I am using a deque. What container might i use that allows me to write `=` on an interator, go forward and backwards while in the middle of an iteration? It seems like i need to keep a copy of `o` as well so i could compare `.begin()` and `.end()`. What is the recommended container and technique?

Comment: using typical iterator semantics, --o.begin() should never be equivalent to o.end(). o.end() represents one-past-the-end of the iteration. Depending on implementation --o.rbegin() MIGHT be the same as o.end(), and conversely --o.begin() MIGHT be o.rend().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deque iterators are random-access. You can increment and decrement them.

The problem is probably that you tried to decrement the iterator returned by `begin`. Doing that is not guaranteed to give you the end of the list — deques aren't circular. (I think it's undefined behavior, so it *could* give you the end, but I doubt any implementations actually do it that way.)

In other words, your test of whether you can decrement iterators wasn't a valid test; the conclusion you drew from it that you can't decrement iterators isn't valid, either. You can decrement any valid deque iterator as long as the new location would also be valid.

Comment: Actually the test was to check if one before begin is the same as one past end. It isnt. So i'd like to know how to check the iterator for bounds. I suppose the best way is to keep a copy of begin() and compare before decrement? -edit- and there no other iterator better suited? (but perhaps as good)

Comment: That's correct. If you're already at the start (or end) of the sequence, don't try to go any farther. Compare for equality: `if (it == o.begin())`. If you're inserting or removing items, beware the rules about iterator invalidation.